# in Sequelize, updating the first instance returned from findAll modifies all instances (mySQL)

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

For example, if Thingie is a Sequelize model with a field named "details", the following code will set the details field of all rows to the same value. (I'm using mySQL at the DB.)

```
Thingie.findAll().then(function(thingies) {
    thingies[0].update({ details: "details about 0" });
});
```

If thingies is an array of 3 items, all three will have their details column set. To be clear, I'm only trying to modify row 0, but all rows are getting modified.

Is this a bug in Sequelize or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding about what findAll does?

Comment: Try adding primaryKey: true to the model definition file in the id field.

Comment: Can you provide the code about setting up `Thingie`? I think having a complete sample code helps us find out what went wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, if you would like to update all the results of findAll, you might want to do the following:

```
Thingie.findAll().then(function(thingie) {
    thingie.forEach(function(t) {
        t.update({ details: "details about 0" });
    });
});
```

This is because findAll returns an array of results and in your example thingie[0] was referring to only the first array element (aka the first database result).

A more optimum solution in my opinion is to use update on a model level rather than an instance level. (see http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/model/#updatevalues-options-promisearrayaffectedcount-affectedrows)

This would end up looking like:

```
Thingie.update({details: "details about 0"}).then(function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: Sorry, my description must not have been clear. (I've updated it.) The problem is that I just modify the first of the items returned by FindAll but what actually happens is that all the items get modified.